# javascript: is there any elegant way to check if string contains any of characters given in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a `string` in my JavaScript code (plain JavaScript, no jQuery or any other libs involved). And also I have an `array` which contains `characters` to be found in a string. I need to check if string contains any of those characters. Of course, it could be done with temporary variable like `found` and array elements iteration.

But is there any way to write nice and compact code? Just in case, I use ES5 (IE9+).

I want to achieve something like

```
var str = "Here is the string",
    chars = ['z','g'];

if (str.containsAnyOf(chars)) {
   ...    
}
```

What is the best way to write that piece of code?

Comment: Writing you own function is best option in my opinion as it gives you optimal performance :) you can also try contains() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), like this

```
if (chars.some(function(c) { return str.indexOf(c) !== -1; })) {
     // Atleast one of the characters is present
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using regular expression:

```js
var str = "Here is the string",
    chars = ['z','g'];

// constructs the following regexp: /[zg]/
if (new RegExp("[" + chars.join('') + "]").test(str)) {
      alert("Contains!");
}
```